# Add Web Root Context to return calls in WSO2 IS 5.7.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I need to add a WebRootContext to all the calls in the WSO2 Identity Server's Implicit Flow so that I can make calls through an API Gateway. I have managed to do this for all the calls I need by changing the 
`<WebContextRoot>/wso2-is<WebContextRoot>`
property as well as changing the name of my webapp folders: `wso2-is#authenticationendpoint` and `wso2-is#oauth2` endpoints. I can now successfully call `http://localhost:9443/wso2-is/oauth2/authorize`.

I also changed the endpoints in `repository/conf/identity/identity.xml` to include the wso2-is root context, specifically the `OAuth2AuthzEPUrl`, so that in the management console this shows up under identity:

[image]
 However, after I login, the application calls `http://localhost:9443/wso2-is/commonauth` which has a return location of `http://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize?sessionDataKey=...` and I can't figure out how to add my context root to the returning call. Where does the `commonauth` endpoint get the location it returns to? I'm assuming there is some property I need to set to make that happen, but I can't find it.

I also tried re-seeding the database with all my changes and this did not solve my issue either. 
I looked in the source code [here in github](https://github.com/wso2/product-is) and couldn't find any references to commonauth or oauth2/authorize that stood out as to where this call is being formed. Any additional details would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the official documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Adding+a+Custom+Proxy+Path), using a reverse proxy is the recommended way to add a custom context path to wso2 products.

However, as I wrote in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54989255), I could complete the implicit flow with local auth successfully with the mentioned configs in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55081626/2910841).

I guess, what you are missing here is `ProxyContextPath`.