# WSO2 IS: How to Set Commonauth Caller Path

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm running WSO2 5.7.0, using OIDC with the Implicit Flow. I have set the context root to `wso2-is`, so the authorize endpoint is located at `http://MY_DOMAIN/wso2-is/oauth2/authorize`. When I begin the flow with a GET call to the `oauth2/authorize`endpoint, I am redirected to `http://MY_DOMAIN/authenticationendpoint/login.do?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&commonAuthCallerPath=%2Foauth2%2Fauthorize...`.

The problem is that it drops the context root and so later in the Implicit Flow I am (incorrectly) redirected to `http://MY_DOMAIN/oauth2/authorize`, which fails because that URL lacks the context root of `wso2-is`. **How/where in the code is the `commonAuthCallerPath` parameter set?**

Comment: can u pls mention how did you set wso2-is as context root ?

Comment: I changed the `WebContextRoot` in repository/conf/carbon.xml to `wso2-is`.

Comment: Is that the only change you did to modify the web context root?

Comment: Because Webapp context root in carbon.xml is only applied for the WSO2 Carbon management console.

Comment: I also added "wso2-is#" to the names of the .war files and the corresponding expanded files with the same name (e.g. "wso2-is#authenticationendpoint.war"). I'm just wondering how authenticationendpoint webapp forms that URL it redirects to after the commonauth endpoint is hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the official documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Adding+a+Custom+Proxy+Path), **using a reverse proxy** is the recommended way to add a custom context path to wso2 products.

If you are not going to use a reverse proxy, I would suggest the following steps to add a custom context path. But, note that I have tested basic authentication with oauth2/oidc only.

1. Set `WebContextRoot` in `repository/conf/carbon.xml` to `/wso2-is` to change the context path of the carbon management console
2. Set `ProxyContextPath` in `repository/conf/carbon.xml` to `/wso2-is`
3. Rename `oauth2.war` and `authenticationendpoint.war` in `repository/deployment/server/webapps/` by adding a prefix `wso2-is#`
4. Update `repository/conf/indeitiy/identity.xml` all the relevent instances of the following pattern by adding the context path `/wso2-is` after the port
   `${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}/xxxxx`
   **to**
   `${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}/wso2-is/xxxxx`
5. Update `AuthenticationEndpointURL`, `AuthenticationEndpointRetryURL` and `AuthenticationEndpointMissingClaimsURL` values in `repository/conf/identity/application-authentication.xml` by adding `/wso2-is` prefix
6. Restart the Identity Server

Do not forget that, this is not the recommended way in [the documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Adding+a+Custom+Proxy+Path).

Comment: This answer got us most of the way there. There seem to still be issues with the implicit flow in OAuth2 regarding the construction of the CommonAuthCallerPath. Thank you.